# Comparar varchar em procedure

Tags: mysql

estou tentando usar o procedure e trigger abaixo no mysql para que ao inserir um registro em uma tabela seja disparado o trigger para subtração do dado valor em outra tabela, mas acontece que está aplicando em todos os registros da tabela alvo e não apenas no registro em que tem o valor comparado. Desconfio ser o tipo varchar que na tabela alvo é do tipo '1.1.1.1'. Abaixo deixo o codigo.

```
# Trigger para atualização de contas.
DELIMITER //
 CREATE TRIGGER TRG_SaldoConta_AI AFTER INSERT ON processos
 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN CALL SP_AtualizaContas (new.rubrica, new.valor);
    END //
DELIMITER ;


# Procedure para atualização de Contas.
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE SP_AtualizaContas( rubrica varchar(45), valor double)
BEGIN
    UPDATE contas SET saldo_anterior = saldo_atual, saldo_atual = saldo_atual - valor
        WHERE rubrica = rubrica;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

No entanto tenho estes outros que funcionam normalmente. Onde o valor comparado é o ano também varchar, tipo '2015'.

```
# Trigger para atualização de dotações anuais.
DELIMITER //
 CREATE TRIGGER TRG_SaldoDotacaoAnual_AI AFTER INSERT ON contas
 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN CALL SP_AtualizaDotacaoAnual (new.periodo, new.dotacao);
    END //
DELIMITER ;

# Procedure para atualização de dotações anuais.
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE SP_AtualizaDotacaoAnual( periodo varchar(45), dotacao double)
BEGIN
    UPDATE dotacoes SET saldo_anterior = saldo_atual, saldo_atual = saldo_atual - dotacao
        WHERE ano_vigente = periodo;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na sua stored procedure e é devido ao facto do parâmetro ter o mesmo nome que a coluna da tabela.

Necessitas de qualificar o nome da coluna. Por exemplo assim:

```
# Procedure para atualização de Contas.
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE SP_AtualizaContas( rubrica varchar(45), valor double)
BEGIN
    UPDATE contas c SET saldo_anterior = saldo_atual, saldo_atual = saldo_atual - valor
        WHERE c.rubrica = rubrica;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

No seu caso, a instrução de update

```
UPDATE contas SET saldo_anterior = saldo_atual, saldo_atual = saldo_atual - valor
WHERE rubrica = rubrica;
```

É equivalente a

```
UPDATE contas SET saldo_anterior = saldo_atual, saldo_atual = saldo_atual - valor
WHERE 1=1;
```

Basicamente irá actualizar todos os registos da tabela indiscriminadamente.

Outra solução é usar ` ([backticks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)). Ficaria assim:

```
# Procedure para atualização de Contas.
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE SP_AtualizaContas( rubrica varchar(45), valor double)
BEGIN
    UPDATE contas SET saldo_anterior = saldo_atual, saldo_atual = saldo_atual - valor
        WHERE `rubrica` = rubrica;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```